# How to disable darker transparent effect in UIPopoverController in iOS7?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, ios7

I use UIPopoverController to popup an view in iPad iOS7 like this:

```
    if (!self.popover) {
        UIViewController *popupVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        [popupVC.view addSubview:thePopupView];
        popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(240, 140);
        self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popupVC];
        self.popover.delegate = self;
    }


    [self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

But when popover active, it make **screen darker** while this effect not affect other views in iOS6.

How to overcome this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the dimming view that is inserted under the popover, there is only one workaround - use a custom `popoverBackgroundViewClass`.

It's complicated, but not as complicated as you might think.

Comment: My popover content is just small rect (240,140). But the dark effect affect whole screen. It's not shadow view.

Comment: @UFO Could you show us a screenshot? It's difficult to understand without seeing it. I didn't actually mean "shadow", I meant to say "dimming view" (English not my native language).

Comment: @UFO That's the dimming view. I believe it's pure black with alpha = 0.15. It's a real pain, especially with passthrough views which are not excluded from dimming. Using custom `popoverBackgroundViewClass` is the only way to go.

Comment: I'm not finish custom one. But this is correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Requiring a custom popoverBackgroundViewClass to prevent fullscreen dimming seems like a lot of work (particularly since the dimming effect makes no sense when using passthrough views and should be off by default). I'm not doubting that it works, but is there no other, more simple way to do this?

Comment: @MichaelSurran Unfortunately, there isn't another way to do it. Check apple developer forums, there are long discussions about it. I believe they wanted to blurred background but later they realized it won't look good without dimming.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to traverse the popover view stack and remove the dimming view manually, as shown here in a `UIPopoverController` subclass:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL showsDimmingView;

....

- (void)presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item
           permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections
                           animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:item
                  permittedArrowDirections:arrowDirections
                                  animated:animated];

    if (!_showsDimmingView) {
        [self removeDimmingView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.subviews lastObject]];
    }
}

- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect
                        inView:(UIView *)view
      permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections
                      animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super presentPopoverFromRect:rect
                           inView:view
         permittedArrowDirections:arrowDirections
                         animated:animated];

    if (!_showsDimmingView) {
        [self removeDimmingView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.subviews lastObject]];
    }
}

- (void)removeDimmingView:(UIView *)subview
{
    for (UIView *sv in subview.subviews) {

        if (sv.alpha == 0.15f && [sv isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UIPopoverViewBackgroundComponentView")]) {
            sv.alpha = 0.f;
        }

        const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(sv.backgroundColor.CGColor);
        if (sv.backgroundColor && (components[1] == 0.15f || sv.alpha == 0.15f)) {
            [sv removeFromSuperview];
        }

        [self removeDimmingView:sv];
    }
}
```

Comment: this approach is fraught with peril

Comment: This approach doesn't work anymore with iOS 8. Do you have another solution?