# How to prevent dark overlay when presenting a UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

In iOS 7, when I present a `UIPopoverController` by:

```
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect 
                                        inView:self.view 
                      permittedArrowDirections:arrowDirections 
                                      animated:animated];
```

The superview it's presented from has a dark overlay applied to it as dimming effect:

[image: example image]

How can I remove this dark overlay from the background view?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898008/how-to-disable-darker-transparent-effect-in-uipopovercontroller-in-ios7

Comment: That looks like a tableview you are presenting from? Are you deselecting the cell before presenting the popover?