# UIPopoverController and Keyboard on iOS 7 results on strange animation

Tags: ios7, uipopovercontroller, uikeyboard, uipopover

On iOS 7, when you present a UIPopoverController, the system adds a UIView with some alpha effect to focus the user on the UIPopoverController. So far, so good.

The problem is that if you have a UIPopoverController that's being displayed from the bottom of your screen, and that UIPopoverController content has a UITextField (or anything else that brings the keyboard), the dimmed UIView animation doesn't follow the keyboard very well.

I've created a sample project to isolate the problem. [Download Project](http://cl.ly/18090T2z2s1C)

And a video of the same issue running on the simulator: [Watch Movie](http://cl.ly/3C160z1q0C0k)

One solution could be to just disable the dimmed UIView [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898008/how-to-disable-darker-transparent-effect-in-uipopovercontroller-in-ios7), but I would like to keep it if possible.

Is there a workaround or maybe I'm doing something wrong?
I'm starting to consider to fill a bug for this.

Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed the same. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your code in a block to disable CoreAnimations implicit animation blocks? Something like this

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions: YES];
// Show your popover:
// [myPopover presentPopover:...]
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: What about a custom UIPopoverBackgroundView?